# How to get top 2 per multi index in Pandas dataframe (generated by pivot_table)

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to show the top 2 results per the first 2 levels of a 3 level indexed dataframe (coming through pivot_table)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[2015,1,'A','R1',70],
              [2015,2,'B','R2',40],
              [2015,3,'C','R3',20],
              [2015,1,'D','R2',90],
              [2015,2,'A','R1',30],
              [2015,3,'A','R3',20],
              [2015,1,'B','R2',50],
              [2015,2,'C','R1',90],
              [2015,3,'B','R3',10],
              [2015,1,'C','R3',10]],
              columns = ['year','month','profile','ranking','sales'])

# create a pivot that sums the sales, sorts the profiles by total sales per year, month and profile
df.pivot_table(values = 'sales',
              index = ['year','month','profile'],
              columns = ['ranking'],
              aggfunc = 'sum',
              fill_value = 0,
              margins = True).sort_values(by = 'All',ascending = False).sort_index(level=[0,1], sort_remaining=False)
```

**Question 1**: how to get only the top two profiles per year month combination?
so

- for: 2015,1: D & A
- for: 2015,2: C & B
- for: 2015,3: A & C

**Bonus question:** 
How to get the sums for the non top 2 profiles and call them 'Other'
so

- for: 2015,1: Other,0,50,10,60 (which is the sum of B&C)
- for: 2015,2: Other,30,0,0,30 (which is A only in this case)
- for: 2015,3: Other,0,0,10,10 (which is B only in this case)

I would like to have it returned as a dataframe to me

Comment: Your sample data only ever has one value for each combination of year, month, and profile. Is this the case for your real data as well?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would post an expected output for 'Question 1' and for the 'Bonus question'

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

without pivoting:

```
In [120]: srt = df.sort_values(['year','month','profile'])

In [123]: srt[srt.groupby(['year','month'])['profile'].rank(method='min') <= 2]
Out[123]:
   year  month profile ranking  sales
0  2015      1       A      R1     70
6  2015      1       B      R2     50
4  2015      2       A      R1     30
1  2015      2       B      R2     40
5  2015      3       A      R3     20
8  2015      3       B      R3     10
```

Bonus answer:

```
In [131]: srt[srt.groupby(['year','month'])['profile'] \
                 .rank(method='min') >= 2] \
             .groupby(['year','month']).agg({'sales':'sum'})
Out[131]:
            sales
year month
2015 1        150
     2        130
     3         30
```

With pivoting: you can try to reset index after pivoting:

```
In [109]: pvt = df.pivot_table(values = 'sales',
   .....:                      index = ['year','month','profile'],
   .....:                      columns = ['ranking'],
   .....:                      aggfunc = 'sum',
   .....:                      fill_value = 0,
   .....:                      margins = True).reset_index()

In [111]: pvt
Out[111]:
ranking  year month profile   R1   R2  R3  All
0        2015     1       A   70    0   0   70
1        2015     1       B    0   50   0   50
2        2015     1       C    0    0  10   10
3        2015     1       D    0   90   0   90
4        2015     2       A   30    0   0   30
5        2015     2       B    0   40   0   40
6        2015     2       C   90    0   0   90
7        2015     3       A    0    0  20   20
8        2015     3       B    0    0  10   10
9        2015     3       C    0    0  20   20
10        All                190  180  60  430
```

Now you can use `rank()` method:

```
In [110]: pvt[pvt.sort_values(['year','month','profile']).groupby(['year','month'])['profile'].rank(method='min') <= 2]
Out[110]:
ranking  year month profile   R1   R2  R3  All
0        2015     1       A   70    0   0   70
1        2015     1       B    0   50   0   50
4        2015     2       A   30    0   0   30
5        2015     2       B    0   40   0   40
7        2015     3       A    0    0  20   20
8        2015     3       B    0    0  10   10
10        All                190  180  60  430
```

Ranking itself:

```
In [112]: pvt.sort_values(['year','month','profile']).groupby(['year','month'])['profile'].rank(method='min')
Out[112]:
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     1
5     2
6     3
7     1
8     2
9     3
10    1
dtype: float64
```